# Creating and listing info for Target Types and Publication targets using core services

Tags: core-service

I figured out how to list target type and publication target names. How do I do the following in core services?

1. List all the items for a publication target; Description, Protocol, login, Language,priority....
2. How do I create a target type
3. How do I create a publication target and all the details that go with it.

Comment: What have you tried to do already?  You'll get a lot of help here if you provide some code samples :)

Comment: It must be a fairly monster implementation to make it worth investing time in writing a web service application to create your target types and publication targets. Most projects I worked on have 2 target types (Staging/Live) - created in the GUI in 10 seconds. You might have a few more Publication Targets, but probably shouldn't (to ensure your deployment is as transactional as possible, use multiple destinations). The only scenario I can imagine is if you are somehow trying to script the creation of your environment - in which case you are surely advanced enough to read the API documentation

Answer (score 8):

Here's how to create a TargetType. Mutatis Mutandis for a Publication Target. (This is powershell with some namespace magic wired up, but enough to show the process. It's the same in C# or whatever)

```
$newTargetType = $core.GetDefaultData([ItemType]::TargetType, $null, $null)
$newTargetType.Title = "foobar"
$newTargetType.Description = "foobar"
$core.Create($newTargetType, $null)
```

As long as I've got the shell open, why not throw a couple of queries at a publication target

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $core.Read("tcm:0-1-65537", $null)

DefaultCodePage   : 65001
Destinations      : {Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.TargetDestinationData}
MinApprovalStatus : Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.LinkToApprovalStatusData
Priority          : Normal
Publications      : {Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.LinkToPublicationData}
TargetLanguage    : None
TargetTypes       : {Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.LinkToTargetTypeData}
Description       : visitorsweb
ExtensionData     : System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject
AllowedActions    :
Id                : tcm:0-1-65537
IsEditable        : True
ListInfo          :
Title             : visitorsweb
VersionInfo       :

PS C:\Users\Administrator> $core.Read("tcm:0-1-65537", $null).Destinations[0].Title
upload.visitorsweb.local
```

Enough to show that it's pretty straightforward to get most of the information you need.

Comment: you'll turn into a shell @dominic cronin